# SQL not ordering correctly by time

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-order-by

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (from_user = :from_user AND to_user = :to_user) OR 
      (from_user = :fromuser   AND to_user = :touser) ORDER BY time ASC";
```

after sometime the messages are not appropriately shown based on time.

They mix it self, can somebody help?

my php time format `$time = date('d-m-Y G:i:s');`

Comment: Well, what are the values in the database of `time`? What do you expect, vs what do you get? How do you retrieve this data?

Comment: What's the column definition in the database for `time`? If it's VARCHAR and formatted `d-m-Y G:i:s`, then you're going to have to cast it to date time and change the format with [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), since it's not in a format that MySQL can easily parse.

Comment: it's as plain text

Comment: use ("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: You should *always* use the proper data-types. Storing times and dates in a varchar/text column will always make it harder to work with.

Comment: @Qirel so you think its a problem with the column data type?

Comment: Yes. It should be of type `datetime` or `timestamp`. You might also get problems with formats as `8:20:30` instead of `08:20:30`, so better use `H` instead of `G`. Though if its current time, you can just use native MySQL functions instead.

Comment: Ok I will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have said in the comments, it's better to have the correct datatypes in your table. But such is life, if you aren't the DBA and have to work with this string data, you can use the STR_TO_DATE() function.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (from_user = :from_user AND to_user = :to_user) OR (from_user = :fromuser   AND to_user = :touser) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') ASC";
```

Comment: cool, since PDO is a prepared statment  does it would work with PDO?

Comment: @Developer Yes, it should.